# How to process Objective-c on AWS

Tags: objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-batch

I have created a data engine in objective-c that requires immense processing. Rather than go buy 100 graphics cards, I'd like to just rent an AWS product like `AWS Batch`, and run my number crunching over there for cheap.

I can export my project as a `Unix Executable` file (runs in mac terminal) but I'm not too sure AWS supports this. Anyone have any ideas?

The engine is coded in Objective-C and my compiler is xCode.

Comment: Is this a one time job?  or will this be user initiated?  Can this code be ported? 
 If so, how much code are we talking about? Is there a database involved?  The more information you can provide, the better we can help you.

Comment: One time job; porting would take too long

Comment: We still need more info:  when you say unix executable - what libs are it dependent on.  When the job is complete, what artifacts does it leave?  We like to help, but we need way more details than you have provided so far.  Im certain AWS batch can handle unix executables, but we need a full picture of what the executable depends on, the version of your OS and what is left behind after it is complete - or does it output to the console?  Please be more specific and if there is a small reference implementation you can share on github, we can take a look and try to help.

Comment: @Taterhead Was able to just launch Unix VMs on AWS and run the files there; ended up being incredibly simple, thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS allows you to launch virtual machines; I was able to simply launch multiple unix virtual machines and run my executable files on them.